# How to fix empty array

Tags: angular, dropdown

I am trying to fetch clients ( id, name ), but I got an empty array.

I am using this code to fetch my clients to populate my NG-DROPDOWN with client id and client name. For now I am getting an empty array.

```
this.clientService.getClients().subscribe((response: any) => {
    for (let data of response) {
      this.clientDropdownList.push({ '_id': response._id, 'name': response.name }) 
    }
    console.log(this.dropdownList)
    }, error => {console.log("error :", error); }
);
```

Service :

```
getClients(): Observable<Client[]> {
    return this.HttpClient.get<Client[]>('/api/clients');
}
```

HTML :

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown class="customDropdown" 
    formControlName="client"
    [placeholder]="'Select Client'"
    [data]="[clientDropdownList]"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
    [settings]="dropdownSettings"
    (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
    (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)">
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

I am expecting an answer with client id and client name into clientDropdownList

Comment: have you checked the server response in your browser debugger? Maybe the server is giving you an empty array?

Comment: Please check the API response, if it is coming empty you can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your template you have both `[data]="[clientDropDownList]"`. For `data` you need to bind the value without brackets.
2. Your `for... of` loop is ok but the assignment is not correct, you are setting values of the array and not the item in the array.

Template code:

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown class="customDropdown" 
    formControlName="client"
    [placeholder]="'Select Client'"
    [data]="clientDropdownList" <!-- removed square brackets around the value -->
    [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" <!-- where is this coming from -->
    [settings]="dropdownSettings"
    (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
    (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)">
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Component code

```
this.clientService.getClients().subscribe((response: any) => {
      for (let data of response) {
        // assign data. instead of response.
        this.clientDropdownList.push({ '_id': data._id, 'name': data.name });

        // or this seeing as the field names are identical
        // this.clientDropdownList.push(data); 
        // you might even make a direct assignment but I am not sure if you are building the array from multiple sources
      }
      console.log(this.dropdownList);
    }, error => console.log("error :", error)
)
```

Comment: With this aproach i got the array with clients (OBJECT) in the console ,, what i need is to fill the list with the client's NAME , and may be the id for the event . can add like  this.clientDropdownList.push({ '_id': data.client._id, 'name': data.client.name });  ??  thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `[data]` binding and bind your `clientDropdownList` to your dropdown. 
Like this:

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown class="customDropdown" 
    formControlName="client"
    [placeholder]="'Select Client'"
    [(ngModel)]="clientDropdownList"
    [settings]="dropdownSettings"
    (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
    (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)">
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Comment: thats what i did , i got NO DATA VAILABLE in the list , and i get the full clients list in my console :)